# JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 8 (char 7)

Tags: python, json

I've followed a tutorial to scrape from a facebook profile and I keep getting this error:
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 8 (char 7)

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Here is my python script:

```
def get_bs(session, url):
    #Makes a GET requests using the given Session objectand returns a BeautifulSoup object.
    
    r = None
    while True:
        r = session.get(url)
        if r.ok:
            break
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml'
#To login
def make_login(session, base_url, credentials):
    #Returns a Session object logged in with credentials.
    
    login_form_url = '/login/device-based/regular/login/?refsrc=https%3A'\
        '%2F%2Fmobile.facebook.com%2Flogin%2Fdevice-based%2Fedit-user%2F&lwv=100'
 
    params = {'email':credentials['email'], 'pass':credentials['pass']}
 
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        logged_request = session.post(base_url+login_form_url, data=params)
        
        if logged_request.ok:
            logging.info('[*] Logged in.')
            break

#Crawling FB
def crawl_profile(session, base_url, profile_url, post_limit):
   #Goes to profile URL, crawls it and extracts posts URLs.
    
    profile_bs = get_bs(session, profile_url)
    n_scraped_posts = 0
    scraped_posts = list()
    posts_id = None

    while n_scraped_posts < post_limit:
        try:
            posts_id = 'recent'
            posts = profile_bs.find('div', id=posts_id).div.div.contents
        except Exception:
            posts_id = 'structured_composer_async_container'
            posts = profile_bs.find('div', id=posts_id).div.div.contents

        posts_urls = [a['href'] for a in profile_bs.find_all('a', text='Full Story')] 

        for post_url in posts_urls:
            # print(post_url)
            try:
                post_data = scrape_post(session, base_url, post_url)
                scraped_posts.append(post_data)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.info('Error: {}'.format(e))
            n_scraped_posts += 1
            if posts_completed(scraped_posts, post_limit):
                break
        
        show_more_posts_url = None
        if not posts_completed(scraped_posts, post_limit):
            show_more_posts_url = profile_bs.find('div', id=posts_id).next_sibling.a['href']
            profile_bs = get_bs(session, base_url+show_more_posts_url)
            time.sleep(3)
        else:
            break
            
    return scraped_posts
def get_bs(session, url):
    #Makes a GET requests using the given Session object and returns a BeautifulSoup object.
    r = None
    while True:
        r = session.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        if r.ok:
            break
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
#Scraping FB
def scrape_post(session, base_url, post_url):
    #Goes to post URL and extracts post data.
   
    post_data = OrderedDict()

    post_bs = get_bs(session, base_url+post_url)
    time.sleep(5)

    # Here we populate the OrderedDict object
    post_data['url'] = post_url
    #Find Post main element
    try:
        post_text_element = post_bs.find('div', id='u_0_0').div
        string_groups = [p.strings for p in post_text_element.find_all('p')]
        strings = [repr(string) for group in string_groups for string in group]
        post_data['text'] = strings
    except Exception:
        post_data['text'] = []
    #Extract post media URL
    try:
        post_data['media_url'] = post_bs.find('div', id='u_0_0').find('a')['href']
    except Exception:
        post_data['media_url'] = ''
    
    #Extract remaining data
    try:
        post_data['comments'] = extract_comments(session, base_url, post_bs, post_url)
    except Exception:
        post_data['comments'] = []
    
    return dict(post_data)

#Scraping FB
def scrape_post(session, base_url, post_url):
    #Goes to post URL and extracts post data.
   
    post_data = OrderedDict()

    post_bs = get_bs(session, base_url+post_url)
    time.sleep(5)

    # Here we populate the OrderedDict object
    post_data['url'] = post_url
    #Find Post main element
    try:
        post_text_element = post_bs.find('div', id='u_0_0').div
        string_groups = [p.strings for p in post_text_element.find_all('p')]
        strings = [repr(string) for group in string_groups for string in group]
        post_data['text'] = strings
    except Exception:
        post_data['text'] = []
    #Extract post media URL
    try:
        post_data['media_url'] = post_bs.find('div', id='u_0_0').find('a')['href']
    except Exception:
        post_data['media_url'] = ''
    
    #Extract remaining data
    try:
        post_data['comments'] = extract_comments(session, base_url, post_bs, post_url)
    except Exception:
        post_data['comments'] = []
    
    return dict(post_data)

#Function for profile URL and creditials for FB
def json_to_obj(filename):
    #Extracts data from JSON file and saves it on Python object
    
    obj = None
    with open(filename) as json_file:
        obj = json.loads(json_file.read())
    return obj

def save_data(data):
    #Converts data to JSON.
   
    with open('profile_posts_data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    base_url = 'https://mobile.facebook.com'
    session = requests.session()

    # Extracts credentials for the login and all of the profiles URL to scrape
    credentials = json_to_obj('credentials.json')
    profiles_urls = json_to_obj('profiles_urls.json')

    make_login(session, base_url, credentials)

    posts_data = None
    for profile_url in profiles_urls:
        posts_data = crawl_profile(session, base_url, profile_url, 25)
    logging.info('[!] Scraping finished. Total: {}'.format(len(posts_data)))
    logging.info('[!] Saving.')
    save_data(posts_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    base_url = 'https://mobile.facebook.com'
    session = requests.session()
 
    # Extracts credentials for the login and all of the profiles URL to scrape
    credentials = json_to_obj(r"C:\Users\E7450\Desktop\GIS702\FBScrapping\credentials.json")
    profiles_urls = json_to_obj(r"C:\Users\E7450\Desktop\GIS702\FBScrapping\profiles_urls.json")
 
    make_login(session, base_url, credentials)
 
    posts_data = None
    for profile_url in profiles_urls:
        posts_data = crawl_profile(session, base_url, profile_url, 25)
    logging.info('[!] Scraping finished. Total: {}'.format(len(posts_data)))
    logging.info('[!] Saving.')
    save_data(posts_data)
```

Comment: You have many uses of JSON here.  Which one gets the error?  Have you printed the string first to make sure it actually is JSON?

Comment: Besides what @TimRoberts said, this code is not fully functional, as you use imported elements that are not visible. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, if this is in fact what you are running, you forgot to close the parenthesis in the return statement of the first function:
`return BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml'`

Comment: Please seach online for that error and also take a look at the data you're trying to parse. Not including it in this question doesn't help either.